# Individual or grouped data in glm

Tags: r, glm

I'm doing glms with poisson and gamma distributed data in R. In literature I've seen models made with individual data or aggregate data (grouped by factors in the model). On this [website](http://instruction.bus.wisc.edu/jfrees/jfreesbooks/PredictiveModelingVol1/r-demonstrations/grouped-versus-individual-data-example.html), it is explained, that the model coefficients should be the same, for grouped and individual data:

However in my case they aren't. They are very similar though. Is one of these ways the correct way and the other wrong? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I aggregated the data on more variables, than there were in the model. When I fixed this, the estimates were the same, just as it's described in the aforementioned website.